# Deep Link does not contain valid required params

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to integrate firebase dynamic links into a React Native app and when I navigate to the prefix url I see the correct json object that signifies the initial domain setup was successful. I have added the associated domain to my project as per the documentation. The issue I am having is that when I open one of the links I have created using the dynamiclinks sdk, I get this error in xcode.

```swift
 [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    socialDescription = "Check out business name on our app";
    socialImageUrl = "http://[apiurl]//rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--046e60135790b0344b8ac127c4e8bcf8ad7cd216/cover.png";
    socialTitle = "\"Business name\" on our app";
}
```

This is how I am creating the link..

```js
            const link = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
            link:'https://myapp.page.link/id=${props.business.id}',
            domainUriPrefix: 'https://myApp.page.link',
            ios: {
                bundleId: 'com.myApp.app',
                appStoreId: '123456589',
                minimumVersion: '12',
              },
            social: {
                imageUrl: `${API_URL}${cover_image}`,
                title: `"Check out ${props.business.name}" on our app`,
                descriptionText: `Check out ${props.business.name} on our app`,
              },
            });

            Share.share({
              url: link,
              title: 'Check this out!',
            });
```

This is what I have added to the appdelegate to handle incoming links

```objectivec
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:
#if defined(__IPHONE_12_0) && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_12_0)
(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#else
    (nonnull void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#endif  // __IPHONE_12_0
  BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL                                           completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,                                                  NSError * _Nullable error) {
 // ...           }];
  return handled;
}
  
  
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
              openURL:(NSURL *)url
              options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {
    return [self application:app
                     openURL:url
           sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                  annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  }

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
              openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
           annotation:(id)annotation {
    FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];

    if (dynamicLink) {
      if (dynamicLink.url) {
        // Handle the deep link. For example, show the deep-linked content,
        // apply a promotional offer to the user's account or show customized onboarding view.
        // ...
      } else {
        // Dynamic link has empty deep link. This situation will happens if
        // Firebase Dynamic Links iOS SDK tried to retrieve pending dynamic link,
        // but pending link is not available for this device/App combination.
        // At this point you may display default onboarding view.
      }
      return YES;
    }
    return NO;
  }
```

and this is the corresponding react native code

```js
  const handleDynamicLink = link => {
    // Handle dynamic link inside your own application
    console.log(' ', link);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);
    // When the component unmounts, remove the listener
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

When I build the link without the social metadata it works but that leaves the link without an image. Can someone familiar with firebase dynamic links tell me what is wrong here? What params is the link missing?

Answer (score 0):

For those who end up here with the same issue, I found out what was happening here:

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3182

The last comment states:

When shared directly to iMessage with the link passed in the url (as opposed to the message) field, apple parses the link but the url path gets replaced with the data in the social field from the dynamic link, which makes the link malformed.

My solution was to use the 'react-native-share' library instead of the native Share extension like this

```js
const url = `${link}`;
const message = `"${props.business.name}" on our app`;
const options = Platform.select({
              ios: {
                activityItemSources: [
                  {
                    placeholderItem: {
                      type: 'text',
                      content: `${message} ${url}`,
                    },
                    item: {
                      default: {
                        type: 'text',
                        content: `${message} ${url}`,
                      },
                    },
                    linkMetadata: {
                      title: `"${props.business.name}" on our app`,
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
              default: {
                message: `${message} ${url}`,
              },
});

Share.open(options)
.then(res => {
                console.log(res);
})
.catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
});
```